# Regex missing matches?

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm doing a matching problem with regexs in python and am using code similar to the following:

```
match = re.findall(r'a(.*)', 'xayaz')
```

I would have expected an output `match = [ 'yaz', 'z']` but instead the actual output is `match = ['yaz']`.

Similarly I would expect `re.findall(r'.*a(.*), 'xayaz')` to return the same 2 matches but instead we get `['z']`.

So my question is why is each of these regex's missing one match that I would expect it to hit? Or am I misunderstanding the findall method?

(first question, apologies for any mistakes, and thanks for any help!)

Comment: Once "yaz" is consumed by the regex, there is nothing left to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookahead to not "consume" any of the match so that you can get overlapping matches

```
re.findall(r'(?=a(.*))', 'xayaz')
```